# Rails routing - how to add scope param to url_for helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

I have resource bio and in views and link for add new bio is:

```
= link_to "Add new bio", [:new, :admin, :bio]
```

If I put resource :bio to scope like this:

```
namespace :admin do    
  scope "/:bio_type", :defaults => {:bio_type => "company"} do
    resources :bios
  end
end
```

This doesn't work

```
= link_to "Add new bio", [:new, :admin, :bio, { bio_type: params[:bio_type] }]
```

My question is how can I add scoped param to url_for helper? And can rails do this by default?

p.s. new_admin_bio_path({bio_type: params[:bio_type]}) works fine, but it's just curious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you cannot make this with array params to `link_to`. You have to use `polymorphic_path` or `new_admin_bio_path({bio_type: params[:bio_type]})`

The reason is that `link_to` calls `url_for` with `[:new, :admin, :bio, { bio_type: params[:bio_type] }]`, which calls `polymorphic_path` with these params.

Check the source code for [url_for](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc092a9cba5fceec38358072e50e09250cf58840/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L111) and for [polymorphic_url](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f937914576c65a01f3a9528d1728720c6c400c5/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L90).
Notice, that `polymorphic_url` takes 2 params - `record_or_hash_or_array` and `options`, but `url_for` calls it with one parameter only.

```
  def url_for(options = {})
    options ||= {}
    case options
    when String
      options
    when Hash
      options = options.symbolize_keys.reverse_merge!(:only_path => options[:host].nil?)
      super
    when :back
      controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] || 'javascript:history.back()'
    else
      polymorphic_path(options)
    end
  end


  def polymorphic_path(record_or_hash_or_array, options = {})
    polymorphic_url(record_or_hash_or_array, options.merge(:routing_type => :path))
  end

  def polymorphic_url(record_or_hash_or_array, options = {})
    if record_or_hash_or_array.kind_of?(Array)
      record_or_hash_or_array = record_or_hash_or_array.compact
      if record_or_hash_or_array.first.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy)
        proxy = record_or_hash_or_array.shift
      end
      record_or_hash_or_array = record_or_hash_or_array[0] if record_or_hash_or_array.size == 1
    end

    record = extract_record(record_or_hash_or_array)
    record = convert_to_model(record)

    args = Array === record_or_hash_or_array ?
      record_or_hash_or_array.dup :
      [ record_or_hash_or_array ]

    inflection = if options[:action] && options[:action].to_s == "new"
      args.pop
      :singular
    elsif (record.respond_to?(:persisted?) && !record.persisted?)
      args.pop
      :plural
    elsif record.is_a?(Class)
      args.pop
      :plural
    else
      :singular
    end

    args.delete_if {|arg| arg.is_a?(Symbol) || arg.is_a?(String)}
    named_route = build_named_route_call(record_or_hash_or_array, inflection, options)

    url_options = options.except(:action, :routing_type)
    unless url_options.empty?
      args.last.kind_of?(Hash) ? args.last.merge!(url_options) : args << url_options
    end

    args.collect! { |a| convert_to_model(a) }

    (proxy || self).send(named_route, *args)
  end
```

So, correct call with the `scope` option should sound like

```
polymorphic_path([:new, :admin, :bio], bio_type: params[:bio_type])
```