# What does a link_to helper expand to when passed an array with a symbol and object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In Rails, (specifically in ActiveAdmin) what does a link_to helper with an array passed as the second parameter do? Where's the documentation for this?

I have this code:

`index pagination_total: false do
    column :name, :sortable => :first_name do |user|
      link_to user.full_name, [:admin, user]
    end`

What does that do? What does [:admin, user] do here?

One confusing thing here is that my ActiveAdmin panel is defined as:

`ActiveAdmin.register Promotions::User, as: "User" do`

So the link actually comes out prepended with the module like so:

`admin_promotions_users_path` which I don't want. This causes an error since the `as:` overwrites the ActiveAdmin path_helper. What I want is:

`admin_users_path`.

In short, I think the error here is that I don't know what a `link_helper` expands to when passed an array with a symbol an object.

Comment: as you have observed `link_to user.full_name, [:admin, user]` => admin_promotions_users_path( I am assuming this is on the promotions controller currently).  I think what you want is `link_to user.full_name, admin_users_path `

Comment: Why doesn't it become admin_user_path? How does the promotions get in there? Does ActiveAdmin hijack the user object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Ruby on Rails - link_to method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), the method signature is `link_to(body, url, html_options = {})`. The `url` parameter can take:

1. A String like `"/users/john-smith"`
2. An Object like `@user`
3. An Array like `[:admin, user]`
4. A path like admin_user_path(user)

If the `url` parameter is a String, it just passes that to the `href` for the link. If the `url` parameter is an Object, an Array or a path, it passes the value to the `url_for` method behind the scenes.

`url_for` will take an Object, determine that the class type is `User`, and look for a corresponding `user_path(@user)` route method. With an array, it first takes any symbols and use it to construct the name of the url helper, then it will take any objects and pass it as values. This is how `link_to user.full_name, [:admin, user]` gets converted to `admin_user_path(@user)` which finally becomes `<a href="/users/john-smith">John Smith</a>`

**Update**

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520016/6615480) (which links to [`url_for`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc092a9cba5fceec38358072e50e09250cf58840/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L111) and [`polymorphic_url`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f937914576c65a01f3a9528d1728720c6c400c5/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L90)) `url_for` takes the input and passes it up to the parent method which for some reason adds the current scope. `link_to` uses `url_for` by default. `polymorphic_path` is the method you require if you want to *"unscope"* it. I tested this concept in a similar situation in my own app and got the same results as @Jwan622.

```
url_for([:admin, user]) # Does not exist
#=> admin_promotions_users_path 

polymorphic_path([:admin, user]) # Exists
#=> admin_users_path
```

Therefore, you should either use this:

```
link_to user.full_name, admin_users_path
```

Or this (if you need to generate the link dynamically):

```
link_to user.full_name, polymorphic_path([:admin, user])
```

Comment: So why is it that in a namespaced ActiveAdmin page, `link_to user.full_name, [:admin, user]` => `admin_promotions_users_path`. When I try to hit the url, I get a "unable to find `admin_promotions_users_path` error from using this link_to with the array (it doesn't fail when I comment the `link_to` helper out)